# how i can give my directory path for sqlite

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am working a in virtual environment with dependencies as follows

```
(venv) D:\Python Codes\python new\LMS>pip list
Package          Version
---------------- -------
click            8.0.3
colorama         0.4.4
dnspython        2.1.0
email-validator  1.1.3
Flask            2.0.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.5.1
Flask-WTF        0.15.1
greenlet         1.1.2
idna             3.3
itsdangerous     2.0.1
Jinja2           3.0.2
MarkupSafe       2.0.1
pip              21.2.3
setuptools       57.4.0
SQLAlchemy       1.4.26
Werkzeug         2.0.2
WTForms          2.3.3
```

my flask app file with modal and routes is as follows

```
rom flask import Flask,render_template,flash,redirect
from flask.helpers import url_for
from forms import Create_Account_Student_form,LoginForm
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////test.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY']='7738ea1a60fd3213606f4d42846d3337'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Students(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name=db.Column(db.String(80),nullable=False)
    email=db.Column(db.String(120),nullable=False,unique=True)
    password=db.Column(db.String(60),nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Students('{self.name}','{self.email}')"

#validatation on login form is remaiing
@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def introduction():
    form=LoginForm()
    return render_template('introduction.html',form=form)



@app.route('/Create_account_Student',methods=['GET','POST'])
def Create_acc_Student():
    form=Create_Account_Student_form()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f'Account created for {form.First_name.data} {form.Last_name.data} !','success')
        return redirect(url_for('introduction'))
    return render_template('create_account_s.html',form=form)

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

it is making database in my HDD if i change path then it give me errors of path or Operaational error

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: The path to your database probably doesn't exist - do you actually have a `/tmp` directory on the current drive? Try to remove any directory references and just keep the filename and see if you can create the db file in the current directory.

Comment: it is now working but it is not showing my database created in project directory

Comment: You are using an absolute path `/test.db`. The URL components are: `sqlite://`, `/`, and `/test.db`.